# You do not have permission to call AppendRow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm pretty new to JS and Google scripts in general and I've been trying to test some of the [Examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) they have, however when I try to append a row it says I don't have permission to do so.

I read some other questions saying that custom functions don't have permission to edit other rows, but that wouldn't make sense if they have a custom function doing exactly that on the tutorial, since it's a bound script (created by clicking on script editor) I assume it should have all permissions set.

Comment: Custom functions (run from a custom function in a cell), can only read data.  You might want to look at the installable "On Change" event trigger.

Comment: Will calling the function as an API work? If not, would it be better to use the native API if my primary objective is to call these functions from an external application?

Comment: Because it's easy to misunderstand even the simplest thing, it's better if you explain exactly what the beginning point is, and what the desired end result is.  Is the beginning point someone editing a cell?  Submitting a form?  Choosing a menu item?

Comment: I want to be able to modify a spreadsheet from a C# application, when looking at Google's documentation a note on top said that making functions and calling them through the API was a more powerful too, so I thought I'd try that. The application should be able to find a row (given a specified value) and remove it, append rows and edit the value of certain cells.

Comment: You can call an Apps Script project published as a Web App, with a GET or POST request.  You can also publish and deploy an Apps Script project as an executable API.  There is also a Google Spreadsheet REST API, and multiple Google Spreadsheet SDK's for different languages.  So, there are a few different options.  But, no matter what option you use, you'll need to authenticate the request through OAuth2 if the project is not published as accessible to anyone, even an anonymous user.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of Google Apps Script and Google Sheets, [scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) are not the same.

A **script** is a broader concept that includes the custom function concept. A script is any [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) that a end-user programmer / developer writes by using Google Apps Script. A **custom function** is a script that will be called from a **spreadsheet formula** in the same way that Google Sheets built-in functions are being called but they have limitations like they can't insert rows.